# How to disable index updating for a single item in Sitecore programmatically

Tags: indexing, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

In my Sitecore web application, I'm creating a new item and do several updates to that item in various places in the code and finally conclude the saving process. This many times of alterations to the item causes to have new table records in the `History` table to be created for index updating as below,

```
Created
Saved
Saved
Saved
Saved
Saved
Saved
Saved
```

This many entries causes the indexing process to check many entries which are not required, but I actually want is to have only two records as,

```
Created
Saved
```

How can I disable the creation of the `Saved` entries temporarily for an item(like having kind of `IndexUpdateDisabled()` context)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should call `item.Editing.BeginEdit()` only once, at the beginning of your flow. Once you reach the final step, you complete the edit with `item.Editing.EndEdit();`

If this for some reason isn't doable in your setup, you could resort to making silent updates. At each step, call `item.Editing.EndEdit(false, true)` and only on the final step use the parameterless overload `item.Editing.EndEdit()`